# How to Handle XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 Error in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, shell, error-handling, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

I am a newer for JavaScript and also for PhantomJS. When I run myfile.js (bears `for` loops) with command `phantomjs myfile.js`, it occasionally(but definitely will) gives out

```
NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.
```

Every time this error occurs, I have to terminate this process(using Ctrl+C in my terminal), and then use bash command below to continue my job

```
$ some bash command to clean the job done before error occurs
$ phantomjs myfile.js
```

It is really depressing especially I have a large `for` loop to do. So, I am wondering whether there is some way to automatically execute these lines whenever it gives out

```
NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

In my rough thoughts, I may have some error handling code within myfile.js, or embed `phantomjs myfile.js` within a shell script file and catch the error it occurs.

Could anybody teach me how to do this?

Here is my main PhantomJS code:

```
    // myfile.js
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var myURLs = ["url1","url2", ... ]; // this array contains more than 10k URLs
    for (i=0; i<myURLs.length; i++) {
      request.open('GET', myURLs[i], false); // synchronous request
      request.setRequestHeader("HEADERKEY","HEADERVALUE");
      request.send();
      if (request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
      } else {
        console.log("Error Code: " + request.status);
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }
    phantom.exit();
```

For private reason, I can't share the URLs within the `myURLs` array. Pretty sorry for that, but I still ask for help if you got some idea from my code.

Comment: Please, share your (minimal necessary to reproduce) PhantomJS code and the code to run it.

Comment: @Vaviloff Have already shared my minimal code in my question body.

Comment: @Vaviloff I run my code with `phantomjs --web-security=no myfile.js`

Comment: 10k URLs? Impressive. What's the use case, if I may ask?

Comment: @Vaviloff I need to check whether those 10k telephone numbers are accessible in my server or not. Those URLs are based on these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, I gotta to answer my own question here.

PhantomJS provides a global error handler called `onError`. It is extremely useful when phantomjs throws out errors.

You can find detailed information here: http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html